# fix name collision with multiple copied files from seperate dll (s) in a test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file-copying

I'm making a translation program.

I have multiple project (s), which are class libraries, one for translating to English and Spanish.

They both have a file called irregulars.txt, which has "Copy if Newer" set, for irregular verbs but when I run the unit tests I get a name collision of both irregulars.txt. So, the Spanish and English irregular verbs are both the Spanish which makes it not work.

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 RC on Windows 10.

How can I stop this name collision?

Comment: what is wrong with my question (-1)?

Comment: how about renaming the file and if thats not possible, placing one of the files in a sub folder/directory.

Comment: @SAm, how would you put it in a subfolder?

Comment: @SAm, that won't be possible because the 2 libraries share a few source files which read the file.

Comment: @trinalbadger587, it is not clear how the interfere each other. But I think you can create either files with different name (with postfixes like _eng, _sp etc) or keep files in different directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be not to hardcode the path of the files, but instead use some kind of configuration. For example, use a configuration file or command line parameters.

An ugly solution would be to use #if and compiler constants to change the source based on which DLL it is used in.